# Finding subsets of a set of points that are all a maximum distance from each other?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have a csv file with the following format:

`thing1_id, thing2_id, similarity`

The similarity is between 50 and 100. I've filtered out all pairs with similarity less than 50, but I do have the full set where the lowest is around 25. There are duplicate comparisons at the moment, i.e. thing1-thing2 is a separate entry from thing2-thing1.

I'm interested in writing a program that will take in a similarity threshold (s) and minimum number of items per set (n), and give me all sets of size n or greater with things that are all at least s% similar to all other elements in that set.

I was thinking a graph might be the best data structure to do this? Where each thing is a node, and the similarity is a weighted edge. I'm not too sure where to go from here without taking way too much memory. This is a set of around 400 things.

Comment: can you give us some more detailed examples

Comment: What kind of detail would you like? The exact result doesn't need to be that specific. My overall goal is to get smaller sets from this overall set to do further analysis on.

Comment: Give some simple examples. For example, suppose you have CAT, HAT, HOT, COT.  CAT is 66% similar to HAT and COT, but HAT and COT are only 33% similar to each other.  So in this case we could have a subset CAT, HAT, but not CAT, HAT, HOT, right?  What would be the desired output in my little example?

Comment: Given that I want sets of say at least 3 and similarity 60%, I would want it to return no sets. If it was sets of 2, I would want (CAT, HAT), (CAT, COT), (HOT, COT), (HAT, HOT).

Comment: Ah, yes! I don't mind overlaps. I didn't want to make the question too long, but for context I'm trying to find groups of DNA sequences that are similar enough (the similarity is fixed and was found using specialized software) to run through a multiple sequence alignment tool

Comment: Let's think about your intuition that this is a graph problem. Suppose we make an undirected graph where the vertices are the items and there is an edge between two nodes if the similarity metric is greater than your threshold. Now the question becomes: identify the cliques of size greater than your threshold -- that is, the fully-connected induced subgraphs. This is known to be a difficult problem to solve either exactly or approximately; good luck! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Comment: Ooh, thank you for the direction!